# Static class with static properties

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to collect all string declarations in my app in a single class, so that they are easy to modify project-wide. I can create a `Strings` class like so:

```
public static class Strings
{
    public static readonly string Title = "App Title";
}
```

or like so:

```
public static class Strings
{
    public const string Title = "App Title";
}
```

The class should be static and all the properties constant. What difference does it make whether the properties of `Strings` have the `static readonly` or the `const` keywords in them?

Comment: `const` *implies* `static`, but the language won't allow you to use both keywords at the same time.

Comment: Perhaps the biggest difference is that `const` would compile, while `static const` wouldn't. Did you mean `static readonly`?

Comment: What do you mean by "centralize all string" ?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know it would not compile. Visual Studio did not indicate any errors until I actually tried to build.

Comment: You might want to look into using a resource strings file (.resx), particularly if there is a possible future need for localisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the difference via a simple example:

```
void Main()
{
    var f = F.Foo;
    var b = F.Bar;
}

public class F
{
    public const string Foo = "F";
    public static readonly string Bar = "B";
}
```

Will yield the following IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       "F"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // f
IL_0007:  ldsfld      UserQuery+F.Bar
IL_000C:  stloc.1     // b
IL_000D:  ret
```

The `const` value of `Foo` is "baked" at compile to the call site, that is why you see a `ldstr` of the value "F" itself, while a `static` field emits a `ldsfld`, which loads the field at runtime, and then assigned it to the local variable `b`.

Making a field both `static` and `const` is a compile time error. Both `const` and `static` are defined on the type, not the instance. More so, a `static` field can be set at run-time, while `const` must be known at compile-time.

If you want to set a bunch of constant values that won't change at run time, going with a `const` should be fine. But you have to remember, that if you change a `const` value, it isn't enough to compile the source holding the consts, you'll have to re-compile anyone who consumes that `const` as well.